# How to store variables in all pages requestScopes within Spring

Tags: spring, model, controller

I usually add objects in my jsp requestScopes using Controllers.

For example, if I need to list **categories** in "localhost/products/viewall", I simply change my ProductsController adding something like

```
@RequestMapping("/products/viewall")
public void viewCategories(Model model) {
    List<Category> categories = service.findAllCategories();
    model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
}
```

so, this method adds a list of categories to my requestScope.

I need to do the same, but for all the pages of the website (since the variable I need will be used in the layout of the site).

How can I add something to all the pages requestScopes with Spring?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have at least two possible options for this:

- Using an [MVC Interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). With an interceptor you can perform common operations for all requests. You can extend [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) and add common model data in `postHandle`
- Using the `@ModelAttribute` annotation within an Controller. You can use this to add common data for all request mappings within a controller. You can also use an [@ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) (with `@ModelAttribute` annotated methods inside) if you want provide model data to all controllers. The section [Using @ModelAttribute on a method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) should provide some additional information for this.