# How to split controller responsibility

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing an application with Spring MVC and i need some help with the design of my implementation, i'm not searching for "the best solution" just ideas how to solve this.

In the application i have a menu on the left side and a central area where the "CRUD" will be, so i will have a controller to handle the central area and handle the user input. But i need some control over the menu itself, it will be dynamic, i'll retrieve some data from the DB and create the menu items.

I'm only starting to learn Spring and the only solution i can see is retrieve the menu items on every controller and send it to the view.

There is other way to handle this so i don't have to include these code on every controller?
I think "Aspects" can solve this problem, but it will be a good solution or will be too costly?

PS: I can't cache the menu items.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried using Interceptor Handlers? https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-interceptor-tutorial/

Comment: Tried it like @FuSsa suggested and it worked, thanks Rossi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will help you :
[Spring 4 MVC Tutorial & examples](http://websystique.com/spring-4-mvc-tutorial/)
it contain a series of Spring MVC tutorial is based on new Spring framework version 4 with help of fully-working examples.

Instead of retrieving the menu items on every controller and send it to the view [you have two possible options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109119/how-to-store-variables-in-all-pages-requestscopes-within-spring)

Comment: Thanks @FuSsa, these tutorials are basic stuff, i got this part covered already.
I need help with some solution so i don't have to retrieve my menu items on every controller/action.
If i'm not clear enough let me know and i will try to do some example.

Cheers.

Comment: u can use one controller.. and use **model.addattribute("menu","menu");**
every time u need to send data from your DB to your menu.jsp page

Comment: Yes, but i'll have to do this on every action. I'm looking for a better approach.

Comment: That's what i'm talking about :) ... i will take a look, thanks @FuSsa

Comment: I could not test it yet, but i will be back to mark as answered later ;)